# print generator array object in python

Tags: python, pandas, printing

I'd like to see content of generator object by printing.

I've applied one function to dataframe and this function will return array as an output. Currently, if I print it shows this message:

```
print(df["events"])

0     <generator object count_ones at 0x000001FDF619...
1     <generator object count_ones at 0x000001FDF619...
2     <generator object count_ones at 0x000001FDF619...
```

Events column data example is this: [0, 1, 0, 2]

Comment: Try `df['events'].apply(list)` it will convert the generator objects to lists. But there will be no point of having generator objects then. pandas doesn't play well with these data structures. Are you sure you that's what you need?

Comment: @ayhan thank you for suggestion. I think my function is still complaining. Once I changed my code, it is complaining that 'TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer' in this line of code 'num_bin_str = bin(num)[2:]'

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your scenario below (I think)

```
r = (i for i in range(3))
s = pd.Series([r], [1, 2, 3])
s

1    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x11c06ff10>
2    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x11c06ff10>
3    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x11c06ff10>
dtype: object
```

This is bad news.  Notice the `at 0x11c06ff10`.  This tells me I have 3 pointers all to the same exact generator object.  That means that if I try to `apply(list)`, I'll get the list for the first series element (maybe) and by the time I get to the second element that generator will have been spent.

```
s.apply(list)

1    [0, 1, 2]
2           []
3           []
dtype: object
```

I say maybe because it could have been spent prior to apply

```
r = (i for i in range(3))
s = pd.Series([r], [1, 2, 3])
list(r);

s.apply(list)

1    []
2    []
3    []
dtype: object
```

I'm not even sure what you even meant to do.  Suppose you wanted a series of lists.  Then solving your problem starts in how you created the series in the first place.

```
r = [i for i in range(3)]
s = pd.Series([r], [1, 2, 3])
s

1    [0, 1, 2]
2    [0, 1, 2]
3    [0, 1, 2]
dtype: object
```

In my example, those brackets `[]` vs parentheses `()` make a big difference.  `[]` indicate a list comprehension which returns a list.  `()` returns a generator. \shrug, I don't know why.  It just does.

Where do you go from here?  Ask another question with more detail about what kind of structure you were trying to build.